# Unable to load libnative-activity.so when CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE is set to anything but debug

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk

After updating NDK to version 19 my application throws a `UnsatisfiedLinkError` with this message "Unable to load native library `"/data/app/com.company.appname-SkXFrxADQ610MNjJr7Ak3A==/lib/arm64/libnative-activity.so": null"` at start, and then terminates.

Anyone knows what is causing this error, and how to resolve it?

*Notes:*

1) When `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` is set to `Debug`, everything works fine, regardless of optimization (`-O`) level or `DEBUG_MODE` setting.

2) This did not happen prior to NDK 19

3) I do call app_dummy(), even though the call is deprecated and not necessary

4) The application uses android_native_app_glue.h/.c i.e no Java at all.

5) The exception libname is "native-activity", and funcname is "ANativeActivity_onCreate"

*Update:*

From the [NDK r19 revision history](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/revision_history) Google says `ndk-depends has been removed. We believe that ReLinker is a better solution to native library loading issues on old Android versions.` I suppose this is relevant, guessing ndk-depends preserved the native activity, but as a native glue application does not contain any java code, how can I apply *ReLinker* from code?

Comment: Is there more to the error log? That doesn't look like a complete error message.

Comment: Hi, the logger says: *NativeActivity LoadNativeLibrary("/data/app/com.company.appname-WlBL-EabtKgAAZKkuTchRw==/lib/arm64/libnative-activity.so") failed: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "fread_unlocked" referenced by "/data/app/com.company.appname.LocalTesting-WlBL-EabtKgAAZKkuTchRw==/lib/arm64/libnative-activity.so"*

Comment: Sorry for the last comment, that warning shows up in Debug as well (where the app works)

Comment: (I'm not using fread_unlocked)

Comment: What warning? UnsatisfiedLinkError isn't a warning, it's a hard error.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, I was referring to the warning in my comment (cannot locate symbol "fread_unlocked")

Answer (score 1):

`fread_unlocked` isn't available until Android P. You can't use that function in an app with a `minSdkVersion` lower than 28.

This shouldn't have compiled unless you've given CMake an incorrect `ANDROID_PLATFORM`, as the symbol wouldn't have been available to link against. If you're building your app with gradle and `externalNativeBuild` then gradle configures this for you based on your `minSdkVersion`. If you're not, you should probably switch to using it as it provides these safeguards.

Comment: Thanks, but after investigating, that warning shows up in Debug builds as well, where the app works. :(

Comment: That doesn't mean it's not being used implicitly.

Comment: I'm using gradle and externalNativeBuild, with minSdkVersion set to 23. I havent fiddled with the ANDROID_PLATFORM. I suppose the "fread_unlocked" warning is unrelated as the same warning shows up in my Debug build, which runs. I suppose it has something to do with ndk-depends and some flag coming from CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.